# Laravel - Load common header and footer to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to load header, footer and the view file from controller in a common template and display the data from controller in the view file. But I get error

> View ['admin.dashboard'] not found.

The dashboard file is present in the admin folder inside views.

#### Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class common extends Controller
{

   public function login()
   {
        $data['title'] = 'Dashboard';
        $data['template'] = 'admin/dashboard';
        return view('common_template', compact('data'));

   }
}
```

#### common_template.blade View

```
<?php echo View::make('includes/header'); ?>

<?php echo $template = "'".$data['template']."'";
echo View::make($template); ?>
<?php echo View::make('includes/footer'); ?>
```

When I add 'admin/dashboard' instead of `$data['template']` directly in `$template`, it loads the dashboard file whereas it doesn’t load when i pass it as string from controller.

#### dashboard.blade view

```
<p><?php echo $data['title']; ?></p> // Printing the data from the controller
```

Comment: You are not using the blade engine. Use `{{$your variable}}` for displaying data in the views.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To include a [Blade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel#Features) template into another template, use [`@include`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#including-sub-views):

```
@include('admin.dashboard')
```

Or

```
@include($data['template']) // This should be the name of template, like 'admin.dashboard', but not path
```

Also, check if the view has the correct name and is in the right directory:

```
resources/views/admin/dashboard.blade.php
```

Answer (score 13):

First of all, your code requires correction as per the Laravel [Blade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel#Features) code standard. Try the below code:

**common_template.blade View**

```
@include('includes.header')

@yield('content')

@include('includes.footer')
```

**dashboard.blade view**

```
@extends('common_template')

@section('content')
    {{$data['title']}}
@endsection
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Instead of include()ing both a header and a footer, one should extend a template.

Answer (score 8):

To include a [Blade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel#Features) template into another template,

**layouts/index.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">

<head>
    <!-- Site Title -->
    <title>{{ $title }}</title> // Dynamic title
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('website/css/main.css') }}">
@stack('css') // Internal CSS
</head>

<body>
    @include('../website/layouts/header') // Include header
    @yield('content') // Include content
    @include('../website/layouts/footer') // Include footer
    <!-- Start footer Area -->
    <!-- End footer Area -->
    <script src="{{asset('website/js/vendor/jquery-2.2.4.min.js ') }}"></script>
    @stack('js') // Internal js
</body>

</html>
```

**layouts/footer.blade.php**

```
// Footer code
<h1>This area for footer code
```

**layouts/header.blade.php**

```
// Header code
<h1>This area for headercode
```

**/home.blade.php**

```
<?php $title = "dynamic title"; ?> // Title

@extends('layouts/index') // Include index page

@Push('css') // This is for internal js
*{
    color: black;
}
@endpush

@section('content') // Section for content
This area for home page content
@stop // Content ended

@Push('js') // This is for internal js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var loggedIn = {!! json_encode(Auth::check()) !!};
        $('.send').click(function() {
            if(!loggedIn) {
                moda.style.display = "block";
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
@endpush
```